# Programmatically upload videos to YouTube using FWT authentication

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, google-api-nodejs-client

Seems like uploading videos to Youtube via its API is restricted to user explicit authorization, and all points that this is only possible via OAuth2 instead of FWT.
Using the V3 API I'm getting a 401 response code, however I can perform read-only operations, like fetch playlists etc...

For server-to-server tasks automation OAuth is not the best solution.

Here's is the test code using node.js:

```
var fs = require('fs')
var google = require('googleapis')
var youtube = google.youtube('v3')

var authClient = new google.auth.JWT(
    'service-account-email@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
    'path/to/key.pem',
    null,
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload'])

authClient.authorize(function (err, tokens) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err)
  }

  google.options({ auth: authClient })

  youtube.videos.insert({
    media: {
      body: fs.createReadStream('video.mp4')
    },
    autoLevels: true,
    part: 'status,snippet',
    mediaType: 'video/mp4',
    resource: {
      snippet: {
        title: 'test video',
        description: 'This is a test video uploaded from the YouTube API'
      },
      status: {
        privacyStatus: 'public'
      }
    }
  }, function (err, res) {
    if (err) {
      return console.error(err)
    }
    console.log('Upload done!')
  })
})
```

Google API node.js client original example:
https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/examples/jwt.js

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I finally have to use OAuth2. I created this node.js/io.js module which does it automatically: https://github.com/h2non/youtube-video-api